# Second monitor goes straight to power save mode on start up

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, blank-screen

I've been using two monitors fine for a few months now but after a windows update one of my monitors is stuck in power save mode.

When pressing one of the physical buttons on it, it says there is no signal coming from the computer and to press any key to wake it up. This is not doing anything.

Monitor is a Dell U2414H model and I'm on Windows 10. I've checked the cables are plugged in and drivers are up to date.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Just to double-check, on the primary monitor have you already tried to right-click on the desktop, choose `Display settings` and select the `Detect` option?

Comment: Try pressing  [Win] + [P] and see what the settings are?

Comment: @Run5k - yeah it was detecting it, just also power save mode for some reason

Comment: So that leads to the good advice from @RoaldvanDoorn ... what mode is set as the default?

Comment: It's ok, it's fixed now, not sure what the problem was but a good ol' restart did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well never mind, after a couple of restarts the monitor decided to get back to working again. Literally nothing was altered.

Resolution was changed to 800x600 on restart so I changed that via display settings.